# Finding Absolute Value In Verilog Data Designated by System C/Xilinx X

Tags: c, verilog, fpga, xilinx, microblaze

I have been trying to find the Absolute value of an integer which is designated to Verilog core using Xilinx SystemC, what I have seen is that Verilog treats the negative number as a positive number.

I have tried all data types : `signed int` , `int`, `Xuint32`.

my SystemC or Xilinx C code is:

```
signed int data,value;
data=-20;value=0;
putfsl(data,0);
getfsl(value,0);
signed int data1,value1;
data=20;value=0;
putfsl(data1,0);
getfsl(value1,0);
```

After getting the values of variables I printed them on Hyperterminal.

On my Verilog side the code was:

```
out <=(in<0)?-in:in;
```

I also tried this code but results were similar

```
if(in<0)
out=-in;
else 
out=in;
```

Kindly help me out!

I have also tried other data types and changed parameters but results have not worked out to be I always get 
The same number I input i.e

```
in<0
```

statement is not being true, I also tried `in<=0;`

Comment: What data type is in and out? Can you post those declarations?

Comment: @Adam12       The in and out data types as i have mentioned already i have used all e.g int,signed int,Xuint32. In all the cases the result remains same.

Comment: signed int data,value;
 these are my declarations, i have also used Xuint32 data,value;

Comment: In Verilog, what are they declared as?

Comment: Well it is reg type both out and in variables in verilog are reg 32bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't help with System C, but based on your comments the Verilog code is using an unsigned type for the signal `in`.

```
reg [31:0] in;
if(in<0) //This will always be false since reg is unsigned
  out=-in;
else 
  out=in;
```

In order for this to work `in` would have to be declared as signed.

```
signed reg [31:0] in;
```

You can still test an unsigned value for a negative value(assuming `in` actually holds a two-complement value) by looking at the MSB.

```
//If negative
if(in[31])
  out = -in;
else
  out = in;
```

Comment: Rather than changing the type of register i think a better way i have been suggested i have posted as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Well i Finally came to find out the answer really worked as suggested by some one.Thanks to Him ([Martin Thompson](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/763/martin-thompson))

The Answer is:
Prior to Verilog-2001 all vector arithmetic in Verilog was unsigned.

In Verilog-2001 you can explicitly call for signed arithmetic, so I think you'll need to cast your in:

```
if ($signed(in) < 0)
 out = -$signed(in);
else
 out = in;
```

Reading matter which may be of interest:

[Signed arithmetic in Verilog-2001 - Opportunities and Hazards](http://www.uccs.edu/~gtumbush/published_papers/Tumbush%20DVCon%2005.pdf)